# How to enable Hot Module Replacement with Create React App + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, webpack-hmr

I would like to enable Hot Module Replacement in my Web App, so I can speed up my development time.

I followed this article: https://duske.me/setting-up-hot-module-replacement-with-create-react-app-and-redux/

And i re-wrote my index.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
import FirebaseConfig from './FirebaseConfig';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import configureStore from './configureStore';

firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and I have created a **configureStore.js** :

```html
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension' // REDUX DEVTOOLS

const configureStore = ()=> {
  const store = createStore(reducer,composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers/index', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store
}

export default configureStore;
```

PS. 'reducers/index.js' is the file where I have a default export for my rootreducer (achieved by combining all reducers with combineReducers())

But nothing seems to work.
Did I miss something ?

Comment: Create a new reactjs app using `create-react-app`. It comes with all the prebuilt features.

Comment: My app Is already created with create-react-app

Comment: Then hot reloading should work.

Comment: It should. But It does not work

Comment: @Shishmm91 You don't need these lines with `replaceReducer` etc., hot reloading works out of the box with CRA. Just follow the standard react-redux tutorial to setup your store. It will hot-reload when you change code in reducers.